# How to fix a problem with paths in visual studio code?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, path

I have cloned a repository from GitHub to VS code. There are several files and folders in it. But for some unknown reason, paths to those file are incorrect. When I try to use them, it seems like a repository is not root. So when I copy a path of txt file for example it shows:

`/Users/me/my_project/requirements.txt`

instead of:

`requirements.txt`

Why it happens and how to fix it? Thanks in advance)